# x86 binary bloat - 32-bit offsets when 8-bits would do

Tags: optimization, binary, x86, llvm

I'm using clang+LLVM 2.9 to compile various workloads for x86 with the -Os option.  Small binary size is important and I must use static linking. All binaries are 32-bit.

I notice that many instructions use addressing modes with 32-bit displacements when only 8 bits are actually used.  For example:

```
89 84 24 d4 00 00 00     mov    %eax,0xd4(%esp)
```

Why didn't the compiler/assembler choose the compact 8-bit displacement?

```
89 44 24 d4              mov    %eax,0xd4(%esp)
```

In fact, these wasted addressing bytes are over 2% of my entire binary!

I looked at LLVM's link time optimization and tried --emit-llvm, but it didn't mention or help this issue.

Is there some link-time optimization that can use knowledge of the actual displacements to choose the smaller instruction form?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you provide sample CC code, with what assembly you'd expect/desire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In x86, offsets are signed. This allows you to access data on both sides of the base address. Therefore, the range of an 8 bit offset is -128 to 127. Your instruction is referencing data 212 bytes forward (the value 0xD4 in decimal). If it had been encoded using an 8 bit offset, it would be -44 in decimal, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: @srking: having a signed displacement is actually quite useful.

Comment: @Stephen: Useful sure, but not compared to the value of a full 8-bits of positive displacement, which are by far the dominant case.

Comment: @srking Negative displacements on `ebp` are often used to reference local variables within a function, as they are placed just below the stack frame in memory.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw True, but EBP stack frames are almost a thing of the past.  -fomit-frame-pointer is becoming a standard optimization because it's an efficiency win and DWARF debug format solves the debug issues.  Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: @srking - So there is now an incentive for keeping the stack frames small. :-)

Comment: @srking: How about the value of having 16-bit and maybe 24-bit displacement formats?  Or else have 7-, 14-, 21-, and 29-bit formats using 1-4 bytes of displacement data, all with the same opcode)?